# When I use UserListAdapter I got a line on "View" word and an error in "parent "

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

When I use `UserListAdapter` I got a line on `View` word and an error in "parent":

```
 public UserListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int x) {
        View LayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(Parent.getContext).inflate
                (R.layout.item_user , null , false);
```

Comment: can you explain your problem little more??. what you want  exactly

Comment: Is this a RecyclerView Adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

`getContext` looks like a function ... so I guess your code line should be

```
View LayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(Parent.getContext()).inflate()
```

after `getContext` is missing in your version ...

Answer (score 0):

You can get context from viewGroup that is parent to your item. Use below code as you are doing it wrong.

```
public UserListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int x) {
        View LayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate
                (R.layout.item_user , null , false);
        //Rest of your code.
}
```